# Is it possible to calculate the integral in this way?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

First. feel free to change the name of the question, because frankly I didn't know how to name it properly.

Question: I should calculate an integral like this.

```
Integral(@(r,theta,phi,k) f(r, theta, phi, k)*sin(delta(k)), rmin, rmax..., kmin, kmax)
```

I have a separate code which calculates the `delta(k)` separately and returns values of `delta` in N points. So, as it takes much time I want to calculate and create an array of delta then put it under the integral. But as the k is a variable in integral, what should I do. Can I pass a data set to the function under integration.

After getting the delta array I tried to fit it to get a function to put it in the integral, but this option is not precise enough.

Comment: Is the symbolic toolbox available? You could possibly apply the `int` multiple times, but this depends on `f`.

Comment: the problem here is that I want to have an array of `delta(k)` before calculating this, but I don't know what points I should select while calculating the integral, because I don't know what is going on inside the integration here. f is a long function, it is not important. what do you mean by using `int` many times?